# Problem in creating multiple json files in python for loop

Tags: python, json, file, for-loop

I am trying to create multiple json files in for loop, I am trying below, but i am getting error below

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\\csv\x0bolume_current_{vol_size}.json'
```

What I tried:

```
storage_info =({"VolumeType": vol_type,"Size": vol_size,"InstanceId": inst_id,"Encrypted": encryption_status,"AliasName": alias_name})
for s in storage_info:
      filename = 'c:\csv\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'
      with open(filename, "w") as f:
         json.dump(storage_info, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

as i get multiple volume size values for example 8, 2 in main loop i need to create a json for each size as one file..like volumen_current_8.json volume_current_2.json like that... anyhelp appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mentioning the right key for `vol_size`.

I am assuming the `storage_info` as `list` of multiple `dict`.

You can do like this:

```py
storage_info = [{"VolumeType": vol_type,"Size": vol_size,"InstanceId": inst_id,"Encrypted": encryption_status,"AliasName": alias_name}, {"VolumeType": vol_type_one,"Size": vol_size_one,"InstanceId": inst_id_one,"Encrypted": encryption_status_one,"AliasName": alias_name_one}]

for s in storage_info:
      filename = 'c:\csv\\volume_current_{}.json'.format(s['Size'])
      with open(filename, "w") as f:
         json.dump(storage_info, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

If your `storage_info` is `dict` itself, then you have to do like this for every `storage_info` you get:

```py
storage_info = {"VolumeType": vol_type,"Size": vol_size,"InstanceId": inst_id,"Encrypted": encryption_status,"AliasName": alias_name}

filename = 'c:\csv\\volume_current_{}.json'.format(storage_info['Size'])
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    json.dump(storage_info, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: I am getting    `filename = 'c:\csv\volume_current_{}.json'.format(s['Size'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers` error

Comment: each time in loop i get that storage_info like this `{'VolumeType': 'gp', 'Size': 2, 'InstanceId': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'Encrypted': True, 'AliasName': 'EBS'}

Comment: s is `{'VolumeType': 'gp', 'Size': 2, 'InstanceId': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'Encrypted': True, 'AliasName': 'EBS'}`. Right?

Comment: yes. each iteration will get all volumes one by one like above

Comment: tried, getting same `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\\csv\x0bolume_current_8.json' `.  huh...it seems its not able to form path ..dont know why :( i am running it in windows

Comment: generally when i write single json i open like this `r"c:\csv\name.json", w ` is this required..confused with string formatting while creating file

Comment: okay, now you are getting the name right and now the issue is having the right path. Right?

Comment: No i just said example even i tried  like this  `filename = 'c:\csv\volume_current_{}.json'.format(storage_info['Size'])
with open(r"{filename}", "w") as f:` . No error , but its not creating files. might be silly mistake i am doing, dont know where i am missing it

Comment: an additional \ in path fixed the issue ` filename = f'c:\csv\\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `filename` variable. The variable is static to a string. You can simply use f-string literels to solve the problem.

Just change `filename = 'c:\csv\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'` to `filename = f'c:\csv\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'`

and everything should work fine.

Complete code

```
storage_info =({"VolumeType": vol_type,"Size": vol_size,"InstanceId": inst_id,"Encrypted": encryption_status,"AliasName": alias_name})
for s in storage_info:
      filename = f'c:\csv\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'
      with open(filename, "w") as f:
         json.dump(storage_info, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: tried  getting same error..its not substituing file path properly :(

Comment: `c:\csvolume_current_8.json ` when i tried to print file name it seems it has problem with \ in path

Comment: What is the value of the variable `vol_size`? Have you declared it or are you getting it from `storage_info`? Because if you are getting it from the dictionaries stored in the variable `storage_info`, `filename = f'c:\csv\volume_current_{s['vol_size']}.json'` should work.

Comment: How did your file name get changed from `'c:\\csv\x0bolume_current_{vol_size}.json'` to just `c:\csvolume_current_8.json`. Expected behaviour was `'c:\\csv\volume_current_8.json'`

Comment: an additional \ in path fixed the issue `filename = f'c:\csv\\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'   `

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue now, all i did add an extra \ in below path. Not sure whether correct way or not it now consider path as correct

```
for s in storage_info:
    filename = f'c:\csv\\volume_current_{vol_size}.json'
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(storage_info, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Edit2:

replaced \ to  / in path it works (some learning that i should use  /)

```
filename = f'c:\csv\\volume_current_{vol_size}.json' 
to   
filename = f'c:/csv/volume_current_{vol_size}.json'
```